# LED on Arduino does not blink

Tags: led, linux

I successful installed arduino, added me to uucp and lock and loaded cdc_acm module.

I use Arduino Uno R3, so I also installed arduino-avr-core.

I have Arduino on /dev/ttyUSB0.

I configured with:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 cs8 9600 ignbrk -brkint -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts
```

I have this folder with these files:
~/Documents/Arduino

```
build.options.json
------------------------------------------------------------
{
    "fqbn": "archlinux-arduino:avr:uno",
    "hardwareFolders": "/usr/share/arduino/hardware",
    "toolsFolders": "/usr/bin"
}

sketch.ino
------------------------------------------------------------
void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
```

After this commands I got output:

```
arduino-builder -build-options-file build.options.json sketch.ino

Sketch uses 914 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

But nothing happened on my Arduino, what's my problem?

Thanks.

P.S. I don't have external LED, I try to use bultin LED.

Comment: did you try Arduino IDE?

Comment: I don't wanna use Arduino IDE. And when I tried it, I got error with avrdude.

Comment: there is no way around avrdude

Answer (score 2):

You invoked the builder, but not an upload to the board. The builder created a hex file.You should use avrdude for upload.

Or use Arduino IDE which does it with a click on a button

Comment: I don't have hex file. I try to search, but I cannot find it.

Comment: turn on verbose output of the builder